# Iframe is not showing the correct page

Tags: html, iframe

How comes I can't use an Iframe for the url http://www.ahv-services.ch/reschweb/rentenform.aspx?

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="600px" scrolling="no" src="http://www.ahv-services.ch/reschweb/rentenform.aspx" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Firefox is showing me that the URL of the Iframe is http://www.ahv-services.ch/errors/error02.htm. This is also the page that is getting displayed in my browser but as you see in src attribute I am not looking for this page.

Edit: Even when you click on that link, it redirects you to the error page. Only when you copy & paste the link, it will show you the correct page.

Comment: They don't want you linking to their page. They serve registered customers only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, `www.ahv-services.ch` is examining the `referer` header sent by the browser (no, you can't supress it) and redirecting if it looks like a third party site is linking directly to that page.

Look at the error message you get (via Google Translate):

> The **calling web server is not registered for the use of this service**. The Web services under www.ahv-services.ch were commissioned by the IGAKIS (www.igakis.ch) by Mathys & Scheitlin AG (www.ms.ch developed). The IGAKIS **provides the services generally after registration**. For more information or an application for a registration, please contact www.ms.ch or www.igakis.ch.

Comment: That's right - although the message implies they're doing it because they serve paying customers only.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question clicking on the link redirects you to the error page, I can confirm this happens for me too.

This means that there is not a problem with your iframe or any of the code on your page, it is the page at http://www.ahv-services.ch/reschweb/rentenform.aspx which is broken.

If you have access to this website then I would recommend you look into debugging this to see if there is an error in the code. If you do not have access to this then I recommend you get in contact with an admin who does.

Comment: Thank you, good to know that. I will inform the admin of this page.